# Appended items not showing when using multi-select listbox

Tags: c#, jquery, listbox

The appended items work perfectly when not including the 2nd Script(which is what gives the listbox a sleek looking listbox with checkboxes in it) - but when I do include it, then it doesnt append the items.

Is there any reason why ?

JQuery:

```
$("#ddlistcategory").change(function () {
        var catItem = $("#ddlistcategory").val();

        $("#ddlistaccountitems").empty();
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "Account")',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Post",
                data: { "i": catItem },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        //alert(key + " " + val);
                        $("#ddlistaccountitems").append('<option id="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
                    })
                }
            });
        });

$('#ddlistaccountitems').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: false,
    allSelectedText: 'No option left ...',
    enableFiltering: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search for something...'
});
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    @Html.Label("Items", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedAccountItems, Model.UserItems, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlistaccountitems", @multiple = "multiple" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling multiselect outside of your ajax method which is populating the element with the options.  As a result you will be initializing it before the ajax has finished, so the issue is most likely that the initialization does not yet have the options to build from.

To fix this, move the initialization into the success method so it will execute after the ajax has finished and all the data that it needs has been created.

Answer (score -1):

Your Ajax call will work asynchronously. That is, the `.multiselect` will execute before the options appended. `.multiselect` will hide your actual `select` and replace it with custom html. So you have to fill it before `.multiselect` execution. add

```
async: false
```

in Ajax call or call

`$('#ddlistaccountitems').multiselect()`

inside that success function.

Comment: You should avoid async: false.  It's counter to the paradigm and also has been removed in jquery 3.X

Comment: Yes.. Its not an optimal solution. better to move multiselect to success function.